# How can I write test for "where" line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, omniauth, minitest

I want to write controller test related password update test. I find authenticated person in the controller's first line with where condition. How can I write test related this line. I couldn't yiled any idea.

**ChangePasswordsController**

```
def update
  person = Person.where(_id: session[:user_id]).first
  identity = Identity.where(_id: person.user_id).first
  unless params[:new_password] != params[:new_password_confirmation]
    identity.password = params[:new_password].to_s
    identity.password_confirmation = params[:new_password].to_s
    identity.save
    redirect_to root_url, :notice => "Password has been changed." + person.user_id
  else
    redirect_to :back, :alert => "Password & password confirmation are not match" 
  end
end
```

**ChangePasswordsController Test**

```
describe ChangePasswordsController do

  setup do
    request.env["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:identity] 
    @auth=request.env["omniauth.auth"]
  end

  it "should have edit action" do
    get :edit
    assert_response :success
  end

  it "should find person" do
     ... 
  end

  it "should find identity" do
     ... 
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you should write a test whether the where finds a person or not. In this context you'd better just check whether the update method calls the find method on Person with the given parameter. Use something like this:

```
Person.should_receive(:find).with(id: <the userid you've setup for the test>) {[Person.new]}
```

It should be able to also check first but I can't remember, something to do with chainstubbing.